# An Acrostiholic Riddle

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

The answer to this riddle is a single English word.

> Likely you'll find me when lending support
>   Or shedding some knots by a slip of some sort
>   Or adding the silver before fitting the frame
>   Keep calm and breathe is the key to this game.

If you have doubts about your answer, it is not correct.

Hint:

> question_asker was absolutely right. The the second line is boaty.

Hint:

> The answer is a very common English word. The clues refer to less common meanings of this word. Nothing really obscure, but definitely not the most common meanings.

Hint:

> Trust the last line.

Hint:

> Trust the title.

Hint:

> Trust me to be a pain in the posterior.

Comment: Hmmm.  This is a good one. I've tried thinking of words I can add "ag" to that fits in a "frame" of sorts. Am I totally off base?

Comment: If it doesn't affect the solution, I'd suggest replacing `before` in the third line with `ere`.  It makes it scan much better.

Comment: *"The answer to the riddle is a single English word."* Oh yes, this must be Hugh Meyers! DVL14 $\color{darkorange}{\bigstar}$ :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I may be off base because I'm not very good at these but I looked at the title and

> Took the first letter of each line LOOK

So I was staring at that and a thought hit me.

> An acrosticolic won't stop at one, right?

I'm keep staring. Right before it says it's  the key?

> Keep Calm And Breathe is BACK backwards in acronym plus it meets with the K in LOOK

I think this fits. To support something can be

> To BACK it

The hint says the next line is boats. I googled the word and

> BACKING is a way to slow a sail boat. 
>  Knots is the speed of a boat so if you're slowing down you are shedding knots in a way and a slip is the place in a marina where you anchor

And also to

> Put something on the back of to decorate or protect and the example in the Google def was a MIRROR

So it can't be a coincidence. The answer has to be

> BACK

Comment: A great first answer! Welcome to the site.

Comment: Let me echo Gamow's welcome and add that this was designed to be a very challenging riddle. Congratulations on figuring it out!

Answer (score 6):

```
Answer:
```

> Eyes?

Likely you'll find me when lending support

> A friendly gaze

Or shedding some knots by a slip of some sort

> Running thread through the EYE of a needle, securing via SLIP-KNOT

Or adding the silver before fitting the frame

> You make a mirror, you're going to see your eyes

LOOK

> yup. With your eyes.

Comment: Plus (and this is totally not confirmation bias), if you consider "you'll" as two words, then take the last letter of the fifth word of each line, you spell "eyes" which further fits the acrostiholic theme. (That being said, while it's a good answer, I'm not sure this is right given it ignores the fourth line.)

Comment: @Alconja Your last point is well taken. So much so that I will put it in a hint.

Comment: The correct answer fits all of the lines.

Answer (score 3):

Answer

> Luck

Explanation

> Title suggests that it is an acrostic, which would lead to the answer being LOOK. The 'rhyme' tag suggests that the alternate spelling LUCK would be more correct, and it also fits the riddle more

Comment: The actual answer fits much more closely than this, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is not:

> Mirror, Reflection, or Glass (or Gemination). The reasoning is available in the edit history if you want to see it. I'm leaving this open on the off chance that I figure out the real answer at some point.

Comment: people usually look into <your answer> to keep calm by taking deep breath when they are nervous.

Comment: @manshu mom's spaghetti

Comment: Not mirror but you are, as usual, going in some promising directions.

Comment: It is not the "or maybe" answer either.

Comment: @HughMeyers Well now I've been thinking about the word "look" for so long that it's lost all meaning.

Comment: If you don't have an answer, delete it.  You can always create a new answer if you come up with one.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain no thanks, I prefer to operate in a manner in keeping with the rest of the site

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain One of the remarks that was edited out is wrong but I believe leads to the solution. If it were right, it would contradict part of the problem statement. This is significant.

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

> Pane

Reasoning:

Likely you'll find me when lending support

> pane- door

Or shedding some knots by a slip of some sort

> pane- strip of cloth

Or adding the silver before fitting the frame

> pane- mirror

Keep calm and breathe is the key to this game.

> pane- piece- peace

LOOK

> window pane

Answer (score 1):

A little tenuous, but I wanna say it's:

> **Bridge**

*Likely you'll find me when lending support*

> A bridge supports roads, railways, etc

*Or shedding some knots by a slip of some sort*

> You'd need to be on the bride of your ship if you're slowing down to land at a slipway.

*Or adding the silver before fitting the frame*

> Bugs me that I can't explain the silver, but you fit the frame of your glasses on the bridge of your nose...

*Keep calm and breathe is the key to this game.*

> Referring to the card game.

Also, an acrostic:

> Bridges lines of a poem together into another word.

Comment: Good reasoning, but you will be sure of the answer when you get it

Answer (score 0):

This is some sort of joke answer:

> it is an hairdresser.

Likely you'll find me when lending support

> If bartenders are the most famous supporters for men, hairdressers are for women :)

Or shedding some knots by a slip of some sort

> [image]

Or adding the silver before fitting the frame

> [image]

Keep calm and breathe is the key to this game.

> [image]

Hope to have stolen you a little smile ;)

Answer (score 0):

Is it:

> Line

Because:

> To get support you may wait in a line or call on a phone line. 
>
>  Knots in a line (rope). 
>
>  Adding AG (silver) to line you get AliGne (align) which is something you'd do to a picture or painting when putting it in a frame. 
>
>  If you're waiting in a line you must keep patient.

I'm starting to think it may have something to do with:

> A ring or marriage or divorce or something.

Comment: Very clever, but not correct. Sorry.